# Calling MATLAB Engine from Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm writing a Cocoa application and I'm trying to link it with the MATLAB Engine to call MATLAB functions. So far I've added the .app/extern/include/ directory (the one that contains the engine.h header) to the header search paths (and subsequently #imported engine.h) and added the .app/extern/lib/maci64 directory to the library search paths (though that doesn't really do anything). I've been looking through the MATLAB documentation and it looks like MATLAB has its own compiler 'mex' for MATLAB engine applications… but clearly that doesn't work for a Cocoa app (and anyway, on my system, the 'mex' command starts PDFTex and has nothing to do with MATLAB). Also, the engine libraries in that directory are in an odd format (.map) which seems to be a debugging symbol file and not a normal Mac library (dylib, a, framework, etc.). Thoughts?